# Best practice for updating list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Wondering if there is a "best practice" approach to updating items in a `list` of `dicts`.

Let's say I have the following and I'd like to update `key1` for each dict in the list

```
data = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
]
```

I know I can make the update in a `for` loop with `range` or `enumerate` like

```
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    data[i]['key1'] = 'value4'
```

I could also use a `list` comprehension

```
data = [{'key1': 'value4', 'key2': d['key2'], 'key3': d['key3']} for d in data]
```

However, I feel this approach may become error-prone to code if there are many key/value pairs in the `dict`s

Is there some other way that I have overlooked?

PS I note that the loop is significantly faster than the comprehension. Does this play into things?

```
In [12]: %timeit [{'key1': 'value4', 'key2': d['key2'], 'key3': d['key3']} for d in data]
The slowest run took 8.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit for i, d in enumerate(data): data[i]['key1'] = 'value4'
The slowest run took 5.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 541 ns per loop
```

Comment: Semantically, these are not the same. The list comprehension creates a new container (including new sub-containers), the second updates the sub-containers in-place

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i do understand. wanting to know what/if there is a best practice

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension create new dict rather than update existing dict so it's slower.
update_2() could be faster:

```
data = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
]

def update_1():
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        data[i]['key1'] = 'value4'

def update_2():
    for d in data:
        d['key1'] = 'value4'

for _ in range(100000):
    update_1()

for _ in range(100000):
    update_2()
```

then `python -m cProfile test.py`

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   100000    0.039    0.000    0.039    0.000 t.py:12(update_2)
        1    0.059    0.059    0.188    0.188 t.py:2(<module>)
   100000    0.090    0.000    0.090    0.000 t.py:8(update_1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.188    0.188 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Yes, the use of enumerate is sort of superfluous here